# Solucion a error Mysql2::Error Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

He creado una aplicacion de rails pero al correr el servidor me sale el siguiente error: 
Mysql2::Error
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Adjunto imagen para ver si me pueden ayudar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Disculpen si la pregunta les suena absurda pero soy nuevo en la programacion con Ruby y en Ubuntu

Gracias de antemano a quien me ayude con sus comentarios

Comment: Debes configurar tu instancia de MySQL y crear un usuario con los atributos suficientes para que se pueda loguear, luego poner las credenciales en `config/database.yml` y llamar a `rails db:setup` para que se cree las tablas iniciales.

Comment: He estado revisando y en un tutorial de internet no configuran nada y aparece la pantalla de bienvenida de Rails al instalar un proyecto e iniciar el servidor

Comment: Quizás usan sqlite, ahí no hay nada que configurar. Si no, busca otro tutorial, puede que esté incompleto.

Comment: Ahora que lo comentas es verdad, no me habia percatado de eso. Conoces algun tutorial de como cambiar la base de datos de un proyecto de rails?

Comment: La verdad es que no, hace ya casi una década que no uso un tutorial básico de Rails, pero google es tu amigo, jeje. Suerte